# Redshift: WHERE timestamp > str vs. subquery slow performance

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table that I want to filter with a where-clause based on the largest timestamp value of an intermediary CTE I have calculated. Why is it that when I compare it against a static date string, it performs fast, but when I compare it against a subquery it comes to a crawl?

Fast:

```
WHERE tstamp > '2018-03-07' --This is fast
```

Slow

```
WHERE tstamp > (SELECT MAX(tstamp) FROM some_temp_cte) --This is really really slow
```

Do you guys have any tips on speeding this up? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some databases have this tendency to re-execute a subquery in the `where` and `select` clauses for every row.  I would suggest moving the logic to the `from` clause:

```
FROM . . . CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT MAX(tstamp) as max_tstamp FROM some_temp_cte) tt
WHERE tstamp > max_tstamp
```

Comment: Hmm. From Redshift's best practices though it suggests not to use cross-joins. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_designing-queries-best-practices.html

Comment: @cvax . . . A `cross join` to a query that returns a single row is fine.